# How do I create a scissors tool that essentially cuts anything that is drawn to the canvas?

Tags: p5.js

I am creating a drawing app on P5.js and I need support on how to create a scissors tool that basically cuts anything drawn to the canvas

Comment: What format do you want to save in? Are you just looking for saveFrames()? https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveFrames. After you 'cut' what will you do? Are you just attempting to modify what is drawn on the canvas or are you trying to do something with the data that is 'cut'?

Comment: Are you wanting to do something like this? https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/cutting-dividing-objects.html If so have you thought about using p5.js get() https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement something like that. How do I go about it? by using that get()??